# why update big array makes "change_protection" kernel call dominating CPU?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

here are the codes `gcc test.c -std=c99`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main() {
        size_t size = (long) 40 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
        int* buffer = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                buffer[i] = 1;
        }
        printf("hello\n");
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                buffer[i] = 2;
        }
        printf("hello\n");
}
```

160G ram allocated in one go, and traversed twice

the first loop runs happily

however the program kinda stuck inside the 2nd loop

with `perf top` showing this

```
Samples: 7M of event 'cpu-clock', Event count (approx.): 14127849698
 74.95%  [kernel]             [k] change_protection
 23.52%  [kernel]             [k] vm_normal_page
  0.40%  [kernel]             [k] _raw_spin_lock
  0.34%  [kernel]             [k] _raw_spin_unlock
```

with `top` showing this

```
top - 10:52:36 up 55 min,  4 users,  load average: 1.16, 1.18, 1.04
Tasks: 240 total,   2 running, 238 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  3.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%s
Mem:  251913536k total, 170229472k used, 81684064k free,    27820k b
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   352816k cac

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
12825 dapeng    20   0  160g 160g  376 R 100.0 66.6  30:38.55 a.out
```

and the best part is now this program doesn't answer to `kill` command any more

gcc version `gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)`

server `AWS EC2 r3.8xlarge`

Operating System `Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.09`

This is related question to [Why does `change_protection` hog CPU while loading a large amount of data into RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919929/why-does-change-protection-hog-cpu-while-loading-a-large-amount-of-data-into-r)

Comment: Can you do an experiment for us, please?  Change your memory allocation line to read `size_t size = ((size_t) 1) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;` and re-run the program.  It should complete almost immediately.  Now increase the 1 to a 2 and run it again.  Again, it should complete almost immediately, 2GB is peanuts these days.  Keep increasing the number by 1 and re-running the program until it gets stuck.  Report the smallest number at which the program gets stuck.

Answer (score 2):

So what happens is:

1. you `malloc` code. That means the kernel maps pages into your program's space; for that, the pages don't even have to be available, its more of a "notify me once you actually access that memory" situation.
2. your first loop sequentially access the pages. Thus, the kernel frequently has to actually assign real memory to your formerly unused pages. Probably, the AWS hypervisor is fast at providing that memory from its pool
3. you access these pages again -- but as bad luck might have it, the pages at the start of your 160GB area might be "far" away now, and getting them back close to the CPU your code is running on might be slow. Remember, you're running on a **VM** on something resembling a NUMA machine.

**EDIT** the fact that it doesn't react to `SIGTERM` etc isn't surprising -- there's no explicit context switch happening and no signal checking done in the `for` loops, so there's no place that your program could react to signals.

Comment: it is taking way too much time, 30minute as shown from top and it has no will to stop, __and__ not responding to my kill command either. very curious, what is the kernel/hypervisor doing now

Comment: I think usage of `madvise()` with `MADV_SEQUENTIAL` might be helpful (or not, I haven't tested this)

Comment: You're right overall, but you're a little confused about signal handling.  If this program weren't stuck *inside the kernel* it would get killed by `SIGTERM` just fine.  A signal can be delivered at any point where the CPU is executing user-space instructions, as long as it isn't blocked.  `ps -ef` will probably report this process is in `D` state, which means *uninterruptible* I/O wait inside the kernel -- that is the only situation where signals don't work.

Comment: @zwol: hm, you seem to be right, but I doubt execution is stuck in kernel land

Comment: @Dapeng: could you run `ps -ef` when your process hangs.

Comment: I see that the OP did post a `ps` line.  It's unfortunate that `ps` uses `R` for both "executing instructions in user space" and "executing instructions in the kernel".  In the kernel, what Marcus originally said about signals is true more or less: they can't be delivered just anywhere.

Comment: [Looking at the code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/mprotect.c#L213), I think it's probably spinning inside the loop on lines 227-233, and if you trace downward, that does a *ton* of work which may well involve hypervisor calls for every single page, and there's no check for needing to reschedule or anything.  On a uniprocessor this would lock up the entire machine until it finished.

Comment: I'm starting to think the answer here is "file a bug report against the kernel".

Comment: @zwol: **please** post this as an answer here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If we can't just leave things as is, which would be my first choice, I would prefer that you edit my observations into *your* answer.

Comment: @zwol: Ok, I see your point. I think your comment is clear enough here. Maybe OP should also get in touch with the amazon guys -- people renting humongous VMs and then not being able to sequentially access RAM does indeed sound like a support case.